# Как правильно выгружать данные с Ajax, если пользователь назад перешел?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, прокрутка

Есть выгрузка ajax по кнопке "еще", человек нажимает и страница скроллится, потом он страницу покидает и когда возвращается, то бразуер на то же место не возвращается, как можно это исправить и чтобы он возвращался на то же место скролла, где он был? Учитывая что скролл работает только по ajax.

Comment: сохраняйте текущий номер страницы в cookie и при следующей загрузке начинайте с него.

Comment: @tcpack4 у него номера страниц. все грузится ajax при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: Именно, что страницы вообще не используются